# How to add text plus the text written from a Parameter type C in ABAP?

Tags: abap

I am working in an ABAP program and I have a question.

For example in C# when we have a String variable: `string name;` , and we want this to be filled with some data from a `textbox` but also add some ohter text.
 
For example:

`string name = "Hello: " + textBox1.text;`,

And I want to ask you how can I do this in ABAP ??? How to add text plus the text written from a Parameter type C?

Comment: Don't use `c#` tag for this question. Your question is all about `abap`.

Comment: soorry it suggested me down there and I just added it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the [`CONCATENATE`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPCONCATENATE.htm) keyword or -- in newer releases -- [string expressions](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abenabap_data_string.htm). Be sure to check the online documentation and sample programs available using the transaction `ABAPDOCU`, it will save you a ton of seemingly basic questions.

Answer (score 2):

CONCATENATE and the concatenate operator && will do it as answered by Jagger and vwegert. To do it with string expressions, you use the below where name is the screen field or whatever that has the name in it (it doesn't need to be a field-symbol):

```
greeting = |Hello: { <name> }|.
```

String expressions are extremely useful as they can be used to build up complex values without declaring extra variables - e.g. they can passed as directly as function module or method parameters without first assigning to a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent operator is `&&`.

So in your case it would be:

```
name = 'Hello: ' && textBox1->text.
```

Comment: This operator is available since Release 7.0 EhP2.